# Just trying to show and alert when i click on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $('#ooo').click( function() {

    alert("jadner");

});

<script>


<a href='#' id="ooo">prueba</a>
```

I expected it shows the alert when i click on "prueba", but it doesn't show anything..

Regards

Javi

Comment: Did you import the jQuery library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use document.ready()

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#ooo').click( function() {

    alert("jadner");
});
});
</script>


<a href='#' id="ooo">prueba</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind the event only after the DOM finishes loading. Wrap your code inside `$(document).load()` event like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ooo').click(function() {
        alert("jadner");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

1 - Make sure jQuery has been included.

2 - Make sure your click handler is in a `$(document).ready(function() {...});` block.

See:

- [`http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

You have to either reverse the order of the tags, i.e. put the script after the link:

```
<a href='#' id="ooo">prueba</a>
<script type="text/javascript">...</script>
```

or wrap the code in a `$(document).ready()` callback:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ooo').click( function() {
        alert("jadner");
    });
});
```

The problem: When your JS is executed, it tries to find the element with ID `ooo` which does not exist yet. Parsing is always from top to bottom. So the script gets executed before the link element is created.

Answer (score 1):

Add `return false;` below the alert. and like Nanne says, make sure you've got jQuery loaded properly

should be `</script>` not `<script>`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$(function() 
{
    $('#ooo').click( function() 
    {
        alert("jadner");
    });
});
</script>

<a href='#' id="ooo">prueba</a>
```